# How to test fiber params

Tags: go, go-fiber

I need to write a test for one of the handlers. Inside the handler I have somethings like:

`ctx.Params("id")`

Is it possible to create a context so that inside the handler Params are not nil?

I tried to change the Params field using ctx.Route().Params, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use [(*App).Test](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/app#test) and let it create a context from the request. Like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func handler(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    id := c.Params("id")

    fmt.Println("Params:", id)

    return nil
}

func TestXxx(t *testing.T) {
    app := fiber.New()
    app.Get("/hello/:id", handler)

    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/hello/man", nil)

    _, _ = app.Test(req, -1)
}
```

```
$ go test . -v
=== RUN   TestXxx
Params: man
--- PASS: TestXxx (0.00s)
PASS
ok      m       0.002s
```